# Vertically Center List Item in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a site that uses Bootstrap 3. I need to vertically align a button along the right side of a list item. In an attempt to do this, I am doing the following:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled list-info">
  <li class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    <label style="width:initial;" class="ng-binding">First Name Last Name</label><br>
    Birthdate
    <a ng-click="viewDetails()" class="btn-icon-round btn-icon-round-sm bg-success pull-right" style="vertical-align:middle;"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

How do I vertically center the icon in the right margin of the list item? I will have additional list items. For that reason, I need it in a list. However, I'm not sure how to do that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way to make it happen is to do something like this:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
<li>
 <ul class="list-unstyled list-info">
  <li class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    <label style="width:initial;" class="ng-binding">First Name Last Name</label><br>
    Birthdate
  </li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li>
      <a ng-click="viewDetails()" class="btn-icon-round btn-icon-round-sm bg-success pull-right" style="vertical-align:middle;"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a> 
</li>
</ul>
```

Then pad the link to your discretion